# repeat, repetitive and repeated distinction when being adjective

Tags: word-difference

> Rahm Emanuel, the embattled Democratic mayor who faces demands to
>   resign over continued citywide gun violence, turned the blame onto
>   criminals and **repeat offenders** during a Monday press conference.

I think ***repeat*** is an adjective in this context, because according to [Free dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/repeat), **repeat**:

> adj.
>   Of, relating to, or being something that repeats or is repeated: *a repeat offender; a repeat performance of the play.*

**Repetitive** and **repeated** can also be adjectives. I'm curious how to distinct these three words, **repeat**, **repetitive** and **repeated**?

For example, *repeated attempts to kill him* **VS** *repetitive attempts to kill him* **VS** *repeat attempts to kill him*?

Any thought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the phrase **repeat offender** swam its way into the main stream after being spawned in  bureaucratic headwaters.  It resembles a database column-name, a label.

Related earlier uses of the adjective suggest a form of headlinese. You might have seen this abbreviated annotation on a concert poster:  REPEAT PERFORMANCE.

**repeated** is formed from the past participle of the verb **repeat**.

**repetitive** has the adjectival suffix -ive.

**repeat** I understand to be a noun that is used adjectivally. Compare:

> We need to do a repeat of yesterday's battery of tests.

The nuanced difference between those words, IMO:

**repeated** applies to that which is intentionally done again.

**repetitive** applies to that which occurs again (and again).

**repeat**  refers to a category of actions or actors rather than applying directly to them.  Compare **emergency measures**.

> He developed a repetitive-motion wrist injury.
>
> Listen carefully. These instructions will not be repeated.
>
> He was not reformed by prison but became a repeat offender.

With respect to your sample phrases:

> Repeated attempts to kill him VS repetitive attempts to kill him VS
>   repeat attempts to kill him?

the idiomatic choice is **repeated attempts**.